# Home button and ApplicationState. Which delegate method is called on relaunch of the app?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsnotificationcenter, appdelegate

In my `AppDelegate` I have implemented the `applicationDidBecomeActive` and set a parameter which can be picked up from `NSUserDefaults` throughout the app.

In the class I wish to invoke when application becomes active I have added an observer:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "appplicationDidBecomeActive:", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

I then tested the code by running the app, then pressed the home button, the relaunched the app from its icon. To my surprise, the `applicationDidBecomeActive` in AppDelegate was not called and the same method in my class was not called either.

I then tested a similar piece of code but with `applicationWillEnterForeground` without changing the observer code in my class.

To my surprise, this time everything worked. With breakpoints in both `AppDelegate` and my class I could see that the `applicationWillEnterForeground`in my `AppDelegate` was called and so was the observer associated method in my class.

What is not clear to me is why the delegate method `applicationDidBecomeActive` is not actually invoked when I relaunch the app AND even more how can the observer know that the app became active w/o the delegate method knowing about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first think is [Apple dev post](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html)

Also [this post](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/) (a little bit old but still can be useful)

Flow can be showed like:

[image]

Comment: application:handleOpenURL: is deprecated in iOS9

Comment: as i wrote - old but can be useful - main idea with some updates for iOS9

Comment: I know what you wrote because I read your answer. Not criticising, just pointing out that in the illustration the only method that is shown, which is deprecated is application:handleOpenURL: ( which I think for an old illustration is pretty good!)